TV program based in electrical shop which set fire with the manager and employee on the roof
I'm trying to think of a UK TV show, I thought it was a sitcom always based in the same store but as I can’t remember any other episodes or find any reference to it after extensive searching I’m not wondering if it was a one off. Maybe it was a one off like the type of sketch you see on Comic Relief or other shows similar. 
It was set in a large electrical shop/superstore much like Currys/PC world.
In the episode I can remember this happens:
An old man turns up for work but the manager (a slightly overweight man with dark short hair) knows nothing about him, the old man informs him that it's some sort of OAP awareness day/week where all of the local businesses have agreed to employ a OAP for the day/week.
At the back of the store the manager has set up a room set up like a living room with a large TV, surround sound system, sofa etc to show off the best products.
The fire alarm goes off and the manager starts evacuating the store, for some reason (I think he's looking for the old man) the manager and the old man cannot exit the store so go up to the roof to signal for help.
There is a massive neon sign on the roof (the letters are not joined together), the manager decides the climb through the neon letter O to signal for help, the old man shouts for him to stop saying it isn't safe. The manager doesn't listen and the letter falls back over them. 
The manager and the old man are now stuck inside a giant letter O and cannot move because there are exposed high voltage wires everywhere. As they are talking the old man reveals it was him who started the fire because he watered the plant on top of the TV and the water went into the TV and set alight, the manager then becomes angry because it was a fake plant!
The old man then has a idea and to the managers shock he grabs a bunch of live wires, instead of electrocuting him it blows a fuse and it is now safe. They get out of the giant letter O, signal for help and are eventually rescued.
Can anyone think of the show I'm thinking about?

Doesn’t ring a bell. Was this a series of shows all set in the same store do you remember? Also what genre? Sitcom?

Yeah from what I remember it was a sitcom always based in the same store. I'll update the question

Do many stores in the UKofGB&NI have a neon sign on a flat roof????  "the letters are not joined together" What were the letters other than "o"?  Cloud 9 perhaps?  Maybe it was a knockoff parody of the NBC comedy "Superstore"  episode in which the store caught fire?   https://hiddenremote.com/2016/08/20/superstore-olympics-episode-recap-going-gold/  From the tone sounds like something commissioned by Channel 4 -- if a single episode, from  one of their comedy anthologies?  Full list at http://www.channel4.com/programmes/categories/comedy
